# How can I Check if a sentence contains different word of same letter in Java Script?

Tags: javascript, string, loops

How can I check if a sentence contains different word of same letter in JavaScript?

For example, if I input

> How can you listen​ if you are not silent​

in a Text Box, `silent` and `listen` contain the same letters and the program should return true, but if there are no words with the same words it should return false.

**Important**:Am not only checking similar words, but also different words with the same letters.

I'm understanding that I'm loop in the inputted string, but I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: hint: `'Listen'.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('')  === 'Silent'.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('')`

Answer (score 1):

```
      function myFunction(str) {

      var res = str.split(" ");
      var data=[];
      var check=false;
      res.map((t,i)=>{

      if(data.indexOf(t)===-1){
        data=[...data,t];
      } else{
          console.log("true")
         check=true;
        }

      })
       console.log(check);
        console.log(data);

    }
var str = "How are you today doing today";
myFunction(str)
```

if we pass a sentence with all are different words  it will shows false in console,if anyone of the word in the sentence matched then it will return true in console

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @vinoth s , But I was thinking that the best way I can achieve what I want was by splitting the words of the entered sentence. Note that I must input one sentence containing different words

Comment: The Program is doing mostly what I was intending it to do,But the remaining problem is that. I want to check words with the same letter. This program of yours is checking exactly the same words, but what I really want is to check words with same letter but not similar words. For example as I said before If I enter --How can you listen​ if you are not silent​. it should return true because all the letters in listen can be found in silent.  thanks once again @vinoth s